# Is there a way to make an "Object.frozen" object throw warnings when an attempt is made to change it?

Tags: javascript, object, console, warnings

I use Object.freeze as a means to prevent myself from breaking my own rules. I would like Object.freeze to speak to me when I try to make a bad assignment. However, Object.freeze simply makes the assignments silently fail! For example, if I do

```
/*
 * Frozen singleton object "foo".
 */
var foo = (function() {
  var me = {};

  me.bar = 1;

  if (Object.freeze) {
    Object.freeze(me);
  }

  return me;
})();

foo.bar = 2;
console.log(foo.bar);
```

the console will log "1", but I won't know that I ever made a bad assignment. This of course can lead to dangerous unexpected behavior in my code, when the whole point of freezing the object was to avoid the unexpected. In fact, I'm more likely to get verbose error output by not freezing the object, letting the bad assignment take place, and having my code fail later on because of the bad value.

I'm wondering if JavaScript has any hidden "immutable object warning" pragma in any browser, so that I can know when I attempt to mutate an "Object.frozen" object.

Comment: That's not supported in IE8 and below, and possibly in some other browsers. I think you're only looking for trouble. At least, test all browsers.

Comment: @Hari, I am not using Object.freeze in any way that changes flow of my program. I only want to use it as a safety tool for myself. I wouldn't dare **depend** on an unsupported function!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Code in strict mode will throw a `TypeError` when trying to assign to an unwritable property ([ECMA-262: 11.13.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1)). But do notice you cannot rely on the error being thrown in browsers that don't fully support ES5 strict mode (such as IE9).

To make your code run in strict mode, add `'use strict';` at the beginning of the JS file or function containing the code and run it in an environment that implements strict mode (see for example this list: http://caniuse.com/#feat=use-strict).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Safari will log 'TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.' when I attempt to make a bad assignment. Of course, I will not be using this in `try {} catch () {}` blocks because of the lack of reliable support for the exception; it is only a coding safety tool for myself. Many thanks!

Comment: So using the strict mode would seem to be the solution. However  it is also good to know that trying to spec the strict mode in functions that use default arguments or rest arguments or destructured arguments  causes an error.    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Strict_Non_Simple_Params

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer isn't working for me. I'm putting this in an answer because I couldn't format it clearly in a comment.

From console in Chrome 109:

```js
> f = () => {'use strict'; const x={a:1}; return Object.freeze(x);}
  () => {'use strict'; const x={a:1}; return Object.freeze(x);}
> x = f()
  {a: 1}
> x.b=4    // (No warning)
  4
> x
  {a: 1}
```