# What is the reason for making Object.freeze() to fail silently?

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecma

Why is that `Object.freeze(obj)` is made to fail **silently** when `obj` is mutated?

Wouldn't it be more logical to throw than error when an immutable object is mutated? Then, it would be to the user's discretion if he wants to wrap a `try catch` around his `Object.freeze(obj)`. Similar to how we need to wrap `JSON.parse()` with `try catch` to avoid errors with empty strings or malformed JSON's.

I wish if the community can make a comment.

**Edit after few answers and comments:**

It is understood that `Object.frozen()` throws error in strict mode. But why is it necessary for the method to fail silently in non-strict mode?

Comment: Taken from MDN " Any attempt to do so will fail, either silently or by throwing a TypeError exception (most commonly, but not exclusively, when in strict mode)."

Comment: MDN link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze Your question is not in sync with the description part of this link

Comment: The intent of the question is to understand why is it made to fail silently when it is meant to be immutable and any applicable use cases if possible. It is understood that it throws error in strict mode.

Comment: Object.freeze will just freeze an object. That is, you cannot change the values of properties inside a frozen object. If you attempt to change the value, then it will fail silently. But your question says "Object.freeze(obj) is made to fail"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make an “Object.frozen” object throw warnings when an attempt is made to change it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119655/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-object-frozen-object-throw-warnings-when-an-attempt)

Answer (score 6):

### `Object.freeze()` does throw, in strict mode.

In strict mode, the following program will throw any time a property is added, mutated or deleted on the frozen object.

Assume we have

```
'use strict'

const obj = Object.freeze({ test: true })
```

Error when adding a property:

```
obj.other = true
// TypeError: Can't add property another, object is not extensible
```

Mutating an existing property throws:

```
obj.test = false
// TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'test' of object '#<Object>'
```

Deleting a property throws:

```
delete obj.test
TypeError: Cannot delete property 'test' of #<Object>
```

If would like to understand strict mode in more detail (highly recommended) have a look at the [official MDN docs for the differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode/Transitioning_to_strict_mode).

The opinions on this topic vary - one would expect mutations of the object to throw because *"you are doing something you should not be doing"* while others might say that if you `Object.freeze()` something, you just want to prevent any modifications to it. And that you successfully accomplish. If it caused applications to crash on mutations, programmers would have no choice but to either check **all objects** they did not create for their frozenness or they would have to wrap all such operations in `try/catch` block. This is simply too much to ask.

#### Note about `try/catch`

You can avoid wrapping property manipulations in `try/catch` blocks simply by checking the object's temperature :

```
if (Object.isFrozen(obj)) {
  // Can't touch this!
}
```

Comment: In my understanding, the objects which are frozen would be something like global immutable constants and the developer knows what they are. Using `Object.frozen()` for just every object is a bad practise and there is no question of using `Object.isFrozen()` in every line. `Object.freeze()` is something like `const` in ES6. The dev knows that the object is a global constant and shouldn't be changed, but if he still tries to go around the rule, he should get an error.

Comment: It is not the case of using `const` or `Object.frozen()` for every variable/object and checking if it is mutable or not. The intent of the question is to understand the necessity of silent fail in non-strict mode.

Comment: I do not think there is a "necessity" - the decision was most likely made due to ergonomics. As you said yourself, it is not feasible to use `Object.isFrozen()` everywhere, therefore it is more ergonomic to just have the operation silently fail.

Comment: Say `Object.frozen()` throws errors in non-strict mode, the developer wouldn't use it to freeze every object. If he wants to, then that should be left to his discretion. The interpreter should be responsible of raising an alarm for faulty code. You wouldn't want to reassign a `const` variable and have  it unchanged.

Comment: Note that it does not matter whether `Object.freeze()` is called in strict mode

Answer (score -2):

I think this is why modifying a frozen object fails silently,

> If error is thrown, execution of code will stop. Try and catch
>   statements are available to handle the error. Is it okay to use try
>   and catch  statements for every line in your code to avoid the error?
>   I think no

**1. Unnecessary use of `try` and `catch` blocks in code**

Let's say an object is frozen at some point in the flow of control. There maybe many lines in code which try to add a new property or modify the value of an existing property in the frozen object. In this scenario, if error is thrown, then you need to add `try` and `catch` blocks in all those lines of code.

**2. Any number of objects can be freezed**

Let's say more than one object is freezed. This will increase the need for more `try` and `catch` statements. It may lead to enclosing each line of your code with a `try` and `catch` block